# how to fix fortify Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration issue

Tags: c#, .net, fortify

I am getting "Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration" high issue in fortify. below is my code.

```
var reportParams = {
        Id: mv.initId,
        Url: "/GetProductDetails/DetailReport?initId=" + mv.initId

    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/GetProductDetails/ConvertHtmlToPdf",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(reportParams),
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: "blob"
        },
        success: function (blob) {
            var fileName = "Savings Initiatives-" + mv.initId + ".pdf";
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
            } else {
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }
        }
    });



   [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
   public ActionResult ConvertHtmlToPdf([FromBody]PdfOptions reportParams)
   {
       string fileName = "Savings Initiative - " + reportParams.Id + ".pdf";
       return File(new CommonService().GetHtmlReportToPdfBytes(reportParams), "application/pdf", fileName);
   }


public class PdfOptions
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting error at

public ActionResult ConvertHtmlToPdf([FromBody]PdfOptions reportParams)

Not sure how to fix this?